Movie about an uncle and his niece
It is about a little curious girl. 
When she lost her dad, she moves to her uncle's house with her mom. The house has a lot of rooms; is very big and mysterious. 
The girl, full of curiosity, starts to examine the rooms, but her hateful uncle catches her and threatens not go there anymore. The uncle isn't a very sociable person, nor very friendly. Suddenly, the niece finds an interesting fact out. The reason why her uncle is unfriendly and always being sad, is that he lost his wife some time ago.
The girl makes some friends and experiences a lot of dangerous adventures with them. Her best friend in this movie is a boy.
Also, I remember a wonderful piano scene. I think the uncle was playing a piano, or the girl (my memories are VERY blury).
The uncle is pretty young (about 30-40 years old) and the girl is about 10-14 years old. 
The language is English.
The movie shows 1850's fashion, but I think it is released in 2000 (I don't know for real lol).

The secret of moon acre is a movie I watched that has some similar parts

When 13 year old Maria Merryweather's father dies, leaving her orphaned and homeless, she is forced to leave her luxurious London life to go and live with Sir Benjamin, an eccentric uncle she didn't know she had, at the mysterious Moonacre Manor. Soon Maria finds herself in a crumbling moonlit world torn apart by the hatred of an ancient feud with the dark and sinister De Noir family. Maria discovers that she is the last Moon Princess and, guided by an unlikely mix of allies, she must overcome her family's pride in order to unearth the secrets of the past before the 5000th moon rises and Moonacre disappears into the sea forever.




